# Turn off Internet Explorer's page-error indicator

Tags: internet-explorer

How to turn off Internet Explorer's error detection? (the yellow icon on the left bottom corner).

Comment: Programmatically from with Javascript?

Comment: Are you talking about `Tools` -> `Internet options` -> `Advanced` -> `Display a notification about every script error`?

Comment: @slugster: That will stop the popup window appearing, but the ! icon will still appear in the corner.

Comment: Tried that.But somehow the messagebox still appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the Javascript causing the error.

Comment: But the error originated from other's website. How can I silent my IE from this error messages?

Comment: I don't think you can. What sort of situation is this, another site in an iframe on your site?

Comment: No. I try to run the sites from the phishtank. If I run using other browser, it is fine. But IE gives a lot of "Internet Explorer script error".